# Couldnt run same python file multiple times in VSCode, getting "Session invalidated Error"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyalgotrade

I have a python file main.py which does some algo trading in finvaisa broker. I want to run the same file mulple times by changing some params etc..

what i did was

-> I ran Main.py in first terminal

-> Opened new terminal in VSCode and ran Main.py again doing some changes

-> Now after sometime the first terminal is having error like "Session invalidated",

My program, connects finavasia broker and places some orders etc.. and if i am running two sessions parallelly, then two programs simultaneuously access the broker and causing issues.
I tried with few other brokers and its working fine with them, only finavaisa is having this issue.

Can anyone let me know is there any alternate way to run the same file in multiple sessions.

May be something like, keeping alive the connection string and that can be used whenever i run any python file at any time?

I am new to python, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.py` file will use the same Port for sending requests to Algo Server which is why you receive an error the second time, as that Port is already running a process. Can you kindly share the socket/config params or details for more clarification?